# heroku run php artisan migrate not migrating anything

Tags: laravel, heroku, migration, heroku-postgres

I am trying to migrate new columns into heroku's postgresql through my Laravel application. I am trying to push the new migrations using `heroku run php artisan migrate` but it does not migrate anything to heroku where I have created all the migrations and migrated to my local server which are running perfectly fine.

I have been facing this problem for quite a long time and couldnt find a solution over internet. I even tried using `heroku run bash` to migrate but it only worked once. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

I dont get any errors it just says `Nothing to migrate`

**UPDATED**

Regards.

Comment: Do you get any error? Post your error message with your question

Comment: No I dont get any error it just says `nothing to migrate`

Comment: Then your migration already done. Do you have another laravel project on this server?

Comment: I checked on the schema where heroku shows the table names and their attributes but its not there. Yes I do have to more projects but I have made the repo and pushing it to the current project

Comment: Seems like your current project database credentials matth with your another database. Check your env. If you give the currect credentials then make a migrate refresh.  `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: I tried refreshing and resetting but its still the same. Do you mean by the username on the local server? I have same un and pass on local server everytime I create a new project and on heroku it randomly generates the credentials so they are not same

Comment: I also checked my other project's database but there are no tables on the production side

Comment: I have checked the credentials on heroku only port no. is same on both config vars